# Fiddler error even though fiddler isn't running

Tags: asp.net, firefox, fiddler

In Firefox I am getting Fiddler errors when I try to debug my application, even though Fiddler is not running.

```
[Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed.
ErrorCode: 10061.
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:63222
```

What is causing this.

Comment: Check if the add-on is enabled.

Comment: It is disabled (FiddlerHook).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler doesn't run on port 63222 by default. There are two possibilities:

1. You configured Fiddler to run on that port, and after exiting it your browser started pulling a cached error page (unlikely)
2. Your browser is configured to use a FiddlerCore-based application which crashed or exited.

Based on the port alone, my guess is that you installed something that installed the adware product named `BrowserSafeguard` which runs such a proxy. Assuming that this isn't a product you want, you should uninstall it using the Add/Remove Programs control panel and then fix your Firefox proxy settings.

Comment: BrowserSafeGuard isn't installed. I did have trouble a while back with another SnapDo trying to take over Firefox. But I thought I had cleaned it up. Perhaps not. (PS: 63222 is my local dev server.)